# Как запустить проект с githab

Tags: node.js

Скачал этот проект https://github.com/thm2/Food-Services-Database-and-App, но не понимаю, как его запустить.

Пытался через node js и выдает это:

```
C:\Users\Hardw\Downloads\Food-Services-Database-and-App-main>npm install
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Hardw\Downloads\Food-Services-Database-and-App-main/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Hardw\Downloads\Food-Services-Database-and-App-main\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Hardw\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-04-26T18_14_41_249Z-debug-0.log

C:\Users\Hardw\Downloads\Food-Services-Database-and-App-main>npm install
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Hardw\Downloads/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Hardw\Downloads\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Hardw\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-04-26T18_15_30_842Z-debug-0.log

C:\Users\Hardw\Downloads\Food-Services-Database-and-App-main>npm install

up to date, audited 1 package in 58ms

found 0 vulnerabilities

C:\Users\Hardw\Downloads\Food-Services-Database-and-App-main>npm start
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Hardw\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-04-26T18_16_35_010Z-debug-0.log

C:\Users\Hardw\Downloads\Food-Services-Database-and-App-main>npm run

C:\Users\Hardw\Downloads\Food-Services-Database-and-App-main>node app.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
  throw err;
  ^
```